# How to create big query in SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE workers (
ID_worker    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name_worker INTEGER UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE equip (
ID_equip     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name_equip TEXT);

CREATE TABLE models (
ID_model     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
ID_equip1        INTEGER REFERENCES equip (ID_equip),
name_model TEXT);

CREATE TABLE work(
ID_worker1    INTEGER REFERENCES workers (ID_worker),
ID_model1 INTEGER REFERENCES models (ID_model) );
```

And I want to create query, for example:
ID_worker / name_worker / ID_model / ID_model
where in first "ID_model" appear models where ID_equip1=1 and in second "ID_model" - ID_equip1=2

Sample Data

```
 Table workers
 /ID_worker/name_worker/
 /1        /Andrew     /
 /2        /Max        /
Table equip
/ID_equip/name_equip/
/1       /equip1    /
/2       /equip2    /
Table models
/ID_model/ID_equip1/name_model/
/1       /1        /BH-1      /
/2       /1        /BH-2      /
/3       /2        /CH-1      /
/4       /2        /CH-2      /
Table work
/ID_worker1/ID_model1/
/1         /1        /
/1         /4        /
/2         /2        /
/2         /3        /
```

I want that result

```
/ID_worker/name_worker/ID_model/ID_model/
/1        /Andrew     /1       /4       /
/2        /Max        /2       /3       /
```

Comment: What is stopping you from creating such a query?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik, I create query of type " ID_worker / name_worker / ID_model " with two LEFT JOIN: `SELECT 'workers'.'ID_worker', 'workers'.'name_worker', 'models'.'ID_model'
FROM 'models'
    LEFT JOIN 'work' ON 'work'.'ID_model1' = 'models'.'ID_model'
    LEFT JOIN 'workers' ON 'work'.'ID_worker1' = 'workers'.'ID_worker'
WHERE ('models'.'ID_equip1'=1)`, but i can't create query with second column ID_model

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, I add sample data and first query in post

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT WS.ID_worker, WS.name_worker, MIN(W.ID_model1), MAX(W.ID_model1)
FROM workers WS
INNER JOIN work W ON WS.ID_worker = W.ID_worker1
GROUP BY WS.ID_worker, WS.name_worker
```

Comment: Thank you, very much! It works! Can I ask you one more question, please? 
What the query will look like if in table "equip" will be 3 entries, for example: third entry /3/equip3/. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Because your end result does not include any data from equip table.

Comment: Sorry, but can you help me with query. I need to add new entry in "equip" table and output query taking into account the new entry. Thank you.

Comment: @KonstantinPenzev, The same query will work for you.